# R Time series data plot - hue + mean solid line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have time series data for over 300 batches and the sample data looks like this:
[image]

Below is an image of what I am trying to plot with the data: With all batches in light hue(light red and light green) and the mean of good and bad groups overlapping the hue trend in solid green and red lines.

[image]

Below is a screenshot of what I have done so far. I used a simple ggplot line graph to plot all batches but failed to turn it to hue. I have also added my code so far.

[image]

```
ggplot(df %>% filter(Timestamp < 250), 
       aes(x=Timestamp, y=Output, group=Batch, color=Type)) +
  theme_hc()+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  geom_line(size=0.9, alpha=0.35)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Update: `dput(head(data, 500))` gives me the following output:

```
structure(list(Lot.Number = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "J", 
"J", "J"), variable = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 
55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 
70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
51, 52, 53, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 0, 1, 2), Value = c(0, 
0, 0, 8, 3, 2, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 221, 200, 
179, 158, 142, 127, 112, 
101, 91, 80, 18, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 211, 170, 130, 110, 91, 
78, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 24, 5, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 229, 
194, 153, 129, 110, 93, 
79, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 83, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 43, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 226, 218, 204, 190, 
174, 161, 150, 136, 126, 
116, 107, 98, 89, 83, 
66, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 96, 1, 0, 
0, 18, 16, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 225, 
198, 180, 161, 144, 130, 
116, 102, 92, 81, 83, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 212, 186, 
154, 136, 117, 104, 92, 
80, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 46, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 203, 185, 160, 137, 
119, 103, 91, 78, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
31, 93, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 187, 151, 124, 
108, 91, 76, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 
32, 0, 0, 5, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 205, 176, 143, 
124, 106, 97, 85, 45, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0
), `outputs[category]` = c("bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", 
"bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good")), row.names = c(NA, 500L
), class = c("cast_df", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you share part of your data using `dput()`? It will be easier to help.

Comment: Using your example data and the code for your plot, you get what you expect:  2 teal-colored lines and 2 red lines representing the four batches.  If you're looking to get the "overlapping hues" as you call them in the example plot, you should use `geom_smooth()` or `stat_summary()` and plot your data, but that is assuming that you have more than one data point for each `df$Timestamp`.  If not, you would have to group.  If you want some assistance, you will have to share your dataset with `dput()`.  I would suggest sharing a `sample()` via: `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 50),])` as example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried it but didn't get the right output. I've updated dput(head(data,500) as an update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you added in your edit matches the one in your question (big assumption here... since all the column names are different), you can try something like the following:

```
ggplot(data, 
       aes(x=Timestamp, y=Output, color=Type, fill = Type)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", alpha = 0.35) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", size = 0.9) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Does the "ribbon" consider the max and min at any Timestamp to plot the hue? I had this doubt looking at the stat_summary for for both ribbon and line.